# Passing parameters from Outlook to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, ms-office

How to pass arguments to Excel VBA code called from Outlook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `Application.Run`:

```
objExcel.Run "MacroName", param1, param2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can execute a macro via the `Application.Run` method. This method takes the macro name as the first argument and then up to 30 parameters that are passed as arguments to the macro.

In Outlook use the following code:

```
Public Sub RunExcelMacro()

  Dim excelApp As Object

  Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  excelApp.Visible = True

  ' open the workbook that contains the macro
  ' or place the macro in a workbook in your XLSTARTUP folder
  excelApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\tmp\book.xls"

  ' run the macro
  excelApp.Run "ThisWorkbook.SayHello", "Hello World!"

  excelApp.Quit

  Set excelApp = Nothing      

End Sub
```

In Excel, add the following method to the `ThisWorkbook` element of a spreadsheet document:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SayHello(message As String)

    MsgBox message

End Sub
```